# Mac Application Name

Tags: macos, cocoa, objective-c++

Our Application deployment structure is something like this:

1. User can download the application form the server,
2. Application name it self contains timestamp, when user requested, on a Specific period of time, it should be prompt user for some more info.

So when user download the Application, Application name would contain APPName_24234442424234.

```
NSString *pAppName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"];
```

it was coming NULL; and then i tried this:

```
NSString *pAppName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleName"];
```

I was expecting it to be name of the application, but it returns the one, that we set during the project creation time.

Is there any way to get the "Changed Name" of the Application programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your server is just changing the name of the app wrapper before sending it to the requester, then the infoDictionary isn't going to change.  You probably want to use

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]
```

or

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]
```

and then parse that string to figure out the actual name of the wrapper.

joe

Comment: To explain further why @Rohan's solution didn't work: `infoDictionary` specifically returns the contents of the bundle's Info.plist file. The contents of that file *are* the `infoDictionary`. If you don't change Info.plist, you don't change the `infoDictionary`. If you change only the bundle's filename, then that's where you need to need to get the information from.

Comment: Also, you can send the path or URL a `lastPathComponent` message to get the filename, and send that string a `stringByDeletingPathExtension` message to strip off the .app extension. You don't need to parse the path or URL yourself; let Cocoa do it for you.

Comment: Good point.  I didn't think to point out the filepath methods.

Comment: not sure, some problem with the info.plist file or any other, but [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] always return nil,